# Template Driven Forms required allows empty string - Angular 7/8

Tags: html, angular, validation, templates

I'm having an issue with my form validation allowing empty strings. `required` works but allows the user to click space. the solution I found online works which is to use ng-pattern `pattern=".*[^ ].*"` but for some reason it does nor work with `textarea`. if the user copys and paste a an html page ng pattern throws an error. the weird thing is when I change the textarea to an input field it works fine. What's the correct solution to fix this. it allows the user to paste certain things but I can't pinpoint what is causing the error when I copied my whole html page and pasted it the textarea for testing. it seems like the spacing inbetween is causing it. StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhvgf1?file=src/app/hero-form/hero-form.component.html

this is what I pasted in the textarea which should not throw an error:  `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newHero(); heroForm.reset()">New Hero</button>
      <i>with</i> reset`

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
           required
            pattern=".*[^ ].*"
           [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
           #name="ngModel"></textarea>
    <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
         class="alert alert-danger">
      Name is required
    </div>
  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newHero(); heroForm.reset()">New Hero</button>
  <i>with</i> reset

  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newHero()">New Hero</button>
  <i>without</i> reset

</form>
```

Comment: 'required works well but if the user clicks the space button the form accepts it.'              do you wish to keep this space? it is sometimes better to trim() it since a space at start is useless.

Comment: as long as the field isn't empty. the issue is space and nothing else

Comment: That seems to work @AndrewAllen running some test now you mind explaining.

Comment: it works it the stackblitz but for some odd reason it freezes my  local app

Comment: You ask for empty but having a space is NOT empty... Again, it is better sometimes to trim the starting space immediately since it is useless.

Comment: true not developer terms but for the user it is. Yeah that may be best to just trim the beginning. I will test that out thanks @TheNsn666

Comment: So you want to allow this space or not ? maybe you can try this regex: \S+.*

Comment: I don't want to allow the space at the beginning serves no purpose

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this pattern for your purpose "(\s*[^\s]+\s*)+"

Comment: When I copied my html page into the input it threw an error

Comment: do you know how to make ng-pattern conditional like: `pattern="condition ? '(\s*[^\s]+\s*)+' : ''"`

Answer (score 1):

you can just create a custom validator and this reusable approach

```js
export class StrictRequiredDirective  implements Validator {
  validator: ValidatorFn;

  constructor() {
    this.validate = this.isStrictRequired();
  }
  validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validate(c);
  }

  isStrictRequired() :ValidatorFn{
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {
      console.log(c.value)
      if (c.value && String(c.value).trim()) {
        return null
      } else {
        return {strictRequired : true}
      }
    }
  }

}
```

[stackblitz demo ⚡⚡](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhvgf1-1zpjey)

Comment: Thanks I was trying to avoid having to make a custom directive since it's a minor issue. I would think form validation should have a simpler solution. or maybe a simple function to throw and error if the field is empty

Answer (score 1):

An easy and reliable solution, is simply to add your form as a parameter, to onSubmit, and then do an additional check at the beginning of your onSubmit function.

**HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(heroForm)" #heroForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
           required
            pattern=".*[^ ].*"
           [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
           #name="ngModel"></textarea>
    <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
         class="alert alert-danger">
      Name is required
    </div>
  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newHero(); heroForm.reset()">New Hero</button>
  <i>with</i> reset

  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newHero()">New Hero</button>
  <i>without</i> reset

</form>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

... 

onSubmit(theForm: NgForm) {
  if(theForm.controls.name.value.trim() == '') {handleErrors(theForm, 1); return;}
  ... the rest of your onSubmit Code.
}

handleErrors(theForm: NgForm, errorCode: number) {
  switch (errorCode) {
    case 1:
      console.log("Empty textarea.");
      theForm.controls.name.setError({Empty_Textarea: true});
    return;
    default:
      console.log("Unhandled error"); 
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will test it out

Comment: But what about showing the red error so the user will know

Comment: @Flash I've amended my answer to include an error handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this pattern \S+.*

It allows the user to use space BUT it won't be valid (if its only spaces):

ONLY SPACES IS NOT VALID IN THIS CASE!

This answer is only to match your initial request, but still I think that trimming this for the user can be a better User Experience.

To use a trimmer directive you can use this:

```
import { ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Output, EventEmitter, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[forceTrim]'
})
export class TrimDirective {

  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
    private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
  handleInput(inputValue: any): void {

      const valueToProcess = inputValue.trim();
      this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, "value", valueToProcess);
      this.ngModelChange.emit(valueToProcess);

  }
}
```

and in template use:

```html
    <input
      type="text"
      forceTrim
    />
```

Comment: In the stackblitz I tested it by copying my html page in there and it threw and error. It may be best to go that trim route you sugested

Comment: trying to avoid using a custom directive but @az264's answer worked well but I still voted so you can break 100 lol